# How to put a ::before pseudo-element above (and next to) the parent element without affecting the parent's position

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a `fieldset` containing a `legend` that has a `::before` pseudo-element and I want this pseudo-element to be positioned above the `legend` without affecting the `legend`'s position.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>THE TEXT</legend>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
legend {
    padding:0 14px;
}

legend::before {
    content:'BEFORE ';
    color:red;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pe3pg84r/)

I tried adding `legend::before { vertical-align:super }` but it puts the `legend` element down like this:

[JSFiddle demo superscript (without success)](http://jsfiddle.net/pe3pg84r/1/)

Any idea's would be welcome to accomplish this.

Comment: What does "above and next to" mean? Can you post an image?

Answer (score 9):

Use `position: absolute;` on the pseudo element like this:

```css
legend {
  padding: 0 14px;
  position: relative;
}

legend::before {
  content: 'BEFORE';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<fieldset>
  <legend>THE TEXT</legend>
</fieldset>
```

EDIT:

If you would like the text to appear beside the legend then use the `left` attribute.

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pe3pg84r/3/)

Comment: You can use both `top` and `left` attributes to position your before element anywhere

Comment: add `left: 2px;` - change the px value to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for my own question, adding `display:block;` and `float:left` to the `::before` makes it works as I want. I could then add margins to the element as I wanted without affecting the legend:

legend {
    padding:0 14px;
}

```
legend::before {
    content:'BEFORE';
    color:red;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pe3pg84r/4/)

Comment: Note that if you use `float: left`, `display` will compute to `block`, even if you used e.g. `display: inline`. So `display: block` is not needed.

Comment: @Oriol Yep I knew that but didn't think about it now, thanks for reminding!